# Can i submit windows phone 7 applications to App Hub from Croatia?

Tags: windows-phone-7

Is it possible to somehow submit windows phone 7 applications to MS App Hub from Croatia?

In legal way, through some company who will do it for percentage?

Thanks

Comment: Wow... Croatia. And I thought Russia was a stretch...

Answer (score 1):

The supported countries are covered here. This list is being expanded and I understand a lot of work is involved getting everything in place country by country.

[App Hub - faq: answers at a glance](http://create.msdn.com/en-us/home/faq)

Until Croatia is on the list I don't believe there is an option at the moment unfortunately. Perhaps you could try and find out from local Microsoft reps how the process is going and express your interest.

Companies may be willing to submit on your behalf for a fee, but I can't tell you what the legal ramifications of this would be. I haven't seen any companies promoting such a service at this stage.